Liquid simulation - how to get the gel/ lip gloss to squeeze out of a bottle?
I haven't done liquid simulations before and I want to learn it for a particular project - I want the gooey gel (lip gloss) to come out of the top of the nozzle and drip to the platform below.
I'm trying to create this bottle

Oriented like this

I've been looking at youtube tutorials but I cant seem to see how to get the liquid to squeeze out from the top and fall on the edges of the bottle onto the platform.

i strongly recommend watching some beginner fluid simulation tutorials. To get your effect you just have to play around with the viscosity parameter. If you really wanna have help for your problem, please provide your blend file, what you have achieved so far and what problem you have there. Then we can help you.

IMO, it's going to be difficult to reproduce this exact  shape with a simulation, because it's faked for a still, if I'm not mistaken
